# google map not working with angular js ng-view

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-2

I am developing a simple angularjs single page application(SPA).
I need to integrate the google map with my application.

but i am facing strange issue while loading google map.
if i load the google map in simple html page all works fine.
but when i navigate to the same page using angular routing only marker is getting display and google map is not loading.

please some one help me on this
Below is the code in controller.

SEMSModule.
    controller('transportMapController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'DataService', '$http',
        function ($scope, $rootScope, DataService, $http) {

```
        window.initMap = function () {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                // center: {lat: -33.866, lng: 151.196},
                center: { lat: 18.63151522815647, lng: 73.85029623056447 },
                zoom: 300,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

            service.getDetails({
                placeId: 'ChIJMyPomIXHwjsRACHB6Yi5VQ4'
            }, function (place, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: place.geometry.location
                    });
                    var myLatLng = { lat: 18.63151522815434, lng: 73.85029623056221 };
                    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatLng,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Hello World!'
                    });
                    $scope.$apply();
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

                        // infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                        infowindow.setContent(place.formatted_address);

                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });

                    window.setTimeout(function () {

                        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });

        };
        $scope.openInfoWindow = function (e, selectedMarker) {
            e.preventDefault();
            google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
        }

        function loadGoogleMaps() {

            var a = document.getElementById("map");

            var script_tag = document.createElement('script');

            script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            script_tag.setAttribute("src", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap");
            //  (document.getElementById("map")).appendChild(script_tag);
            (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);


        }

        loadGoogleMaps();


    }]);
```

Comment: have to initialize in a directive...not in controller which may run before elements even exist

Comment: Thanks charlietfl it working now. But when i try to drag the map i am not able to see the new location i think the map is displaying in static (fix) mode

Comment: think of some way to execute this code when your angular route is called...because in your case the controller is executed when your elements even does'nt exist